# Magento 2 - knockoutjs template ignores script tag

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I try to add a script tag with a `console.log("hello world");` message in the knockoutjs template **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html**

This is the template for the cart summary in the cart. ( the sidebar at the right side ) where the shipping methods are showing if you expand that section

[image]

I just added this code at the end of the file:

```
<script>
    console.log("Hello world!");
</script>
```

Then I flushed the cache and also flushed the browser cache and reloaded the site, but the console log is not showing if the shipping methods load.

The script tag is in the source code, but it is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes against the whole point of using Knockout, I suspect it will never work as either KO or Magento are preventing it from being invoked.

But regardless, you shouldn't be adding script tags here. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Most likely you will be better off using the `afterRender` method to invoke your function.

```
<div afterRender="yourComponentFunctionHere"></div>
```